# VS Code extension that follows CSS include

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hope I missed it (cause I've spent a little bit of time searching for it) and you guys can actually point me towards a Visual Studio Code extension that allows clicking in the HTML file on a class name and it takes you to the class definition in the included CSS file. Neither Intellisense, nor HTML CSS Support seem to do that.

I organized my CSS file so the information is easier to find/follow but it would still save a lot of time if I could just follow through to the style definition.

So are you aware of any such extension? Or any other method that would enable the mentioned behaviour?